# Has this strong number theoretic conjecture of Euler been proved, and where could I find such a proof?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

Polya cites this work of Euler as an example of a conjecture which Euler considered impossible to doubt, and yet still needing a demonstration.

It is on pages 90-98 of "Induction and Analogy in Mathematics", which is volume I of "Mathematics and Plausible Reasoning", Princeton 1954. The reference to Euler is in a footnote on page 90.  (Opera Omnia ser 1 vol 2 p 241-253).

The conjecture is a recursion formula for the sum of the divisors of any integer, it is stated on page 93 of Polya.

Thanks for any help.

**Edit:** In response to comments, here is the conjecture. For $n \geq 1$, let $\sigma(n) = \sum_{d|n} d$ be the sum of divisors of $n$. Euler conjectures the remarkable formula

$$\begin{align*}
&\ \sigma(n)\\ 
=&\ \sigma(n-1) + \sigma(n-2) - \sigma(n-5) - \sigma(n-7) + \sigma(n-12) + \sigma(n-15) - \sigma(n-22) + \ldots \\
=&\ \sum_{k \geq 1} (-1)^{\text{floor}\left(\frac{k-1}{2}\right)} \sigma(n - f(k))
\end{align*}
$$

where $f(k)$ is defined recursively by $f(1) = 1$ and $f(k) = f(k-1) + \frac{k}{2}$ if $k$ is even, $f(k) = f(k-1) + k$ if $k$ is odd, for all $k > 1$. (Euler stipulates that $\sigma(n - f(k)) := 0$ if $n - f(k) < 0$, and one should substitute $n$ for $\sigma(0)$ if such a summand should arise on the right.)

My question is whether this has ever been proved, and if so where I could find the proof.

Comment: could you post the recursion?

Comment: indeed, would you think people here would dig up that reference to see what you mean?

Comment: Polya's book is online here: https://archive.org/stream/Induction_And_Analogy_In_Mathematics_1_#page/n115/mode/2up

Comment: Oh, I think the author (who is a well-established mathematician -- welcome to MO, Professor Hersh!) made it pretty clear that he meant the conjecture on page 93. I have written it out.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Euler *proved* that formula. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189157/recursive-number-of-divisors-function for some references.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think you're right! The pages that come after seem to give the argument.

Comment: Search for "Euler's pentagonal number formula".

Comment: There still seems to be room for confusion, since the pentagonal number formula as described at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem is about the generating function for the number of partitions, whereas the present question is about the generating function for the sum of divisors. (One of the references of Gerry Myerson's math.stackexchange post is open only to invited viewers of a blog.) If this is reopened, as seems likely, it might be nice to have details written out; I shouldn't think it would be difficult.

Answer (score 21):

You can find the outline of a proof of this recursion relation in [Surprising Connections between Partitions and Divisors](http://www.rowan.edu/colleges/csm/departments/math/facultystaff/osler/89%20Surprising%20Connection%20Between%20Partitions%20and%20Divisors.pdf.pdf). The line of reasoning first derives the recursion relation for the number of partitions $p(n)$ of $n$ from Euler's pentagonal number theorem, and then shows that the sum of divisors $\sigma(n)$ has the same recursion relation as $p(n)$.

Comment: Nice find. Theorem 2 on page 285 seems particularly relevant to the question of the OP.

Comment: Nice find indeed. A similar treatment can be found in http://euler.genepeer.com/eulers-pentagonal-number-theorem/